# Tried to block a click bombing bot in htaccess but it's still getting through. How can I block it for good?

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, bots, adsense

My ads are frequently clicked by bots from the domain "amazonaws". After doing some research on Google, I found that others have [experienced this problem](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/D1xt59CEdGI) as well. The bots are coming from random IP addresses and random User-Agents. The only thing that remains consistent is the domain. Since I only get bots from amazonaws, I'd like to just block the entire domain.

I've added the following code to my htaccess file, but my analytics still reports them returning to my site frequently:

```
<Limit GET> 
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
deny from amazonaws.com
deny from .amazonaws.com
</Limit>
```

This has been an ongoing issue for some time. I had to remove my adsense in order to keep from being blocked. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Also block them using `robots.txt`

Comment: I'll try blocking them using robots.txt, but I'm not sure if they'll just ignore the block or not

Answer (score 2):

Can you this code also in same `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}   \.amazonaws\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```